# Multiple versions of .gitlab-ci.yml in multiple branches

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

If different branches in the repository have different .gitlab-ci.yml, then which would would be considered by the gitlab CI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is dependent on which branch you are pushing to (and how your `gitlab-ci.yml` file is setup.

For example:

- When you are on a branch (say develop), and you push to develop, GitLab would build develop's `gitlab-ci.yml` file.
- If you are on another branch (say feature), and you push to feature, GitLab would build feature's `gitlab-ci.yml` file.